# Reading a value from a register( which is declared as internal signal)in my design and displaying it transcript window

Tags: tcl, modelsim

Is there any way to read a value from a register which is an internal signal in my module and displaying it in the modelsim transcript window using a Tcl script?

I am looking for a proper command for use solving the above problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the Manual pages of Modelsim v10.3a you can find the following command for displaying signal values:

> **examine**
>
> ... It examines one or more objects and displays current values (or the values at a specified previous time) in the Transcript window.
>   The following objects can be examined:
>
> - VHDL — signals, shared variables, process variables, constants, generics, and FILE objects
> - Verilog — nets, registers, parameters, and variables.
>
> To display a previous value, specify the desired time using the -time option.

**Note** that this command requires the full path to your register (see example below).

For future reference, if you desire to display memory values take a look at *mem save* and *mem display* commands.

**Example**

Suppose you have the following description snippet:

```
entity core is
   port ( ... );
end core;

architecture behav of core is
   signal regA : std_logic;
begin
   ....
   -- here your regA signal is assigned some values
end behav;
```

which is instantiated in your testbench as

```
entity tb
end

architecture behav of tb is
begin
  UUT: entity work.core
  port map ( ... );

end behav;
```

Once you've compiled your files you must run the simulation up to the moment (or past) where you want to display the signal value.

`run 30 ns`

The command below display regA value at 30 ns:

`examine /tb/core/regA`

... and this recover its value at 10 ns:

`examine -time 10 ns /tb/core/regA`

Comment: Thanks Mr. Felipe for your suggestion but I still left with a doubt like how to use that "show" command.

Comment: I made some changes to my answer to correct my mistake. :)